# Create text document of every file in a directory recursively

Tags: bash, terminal, ls

Part of a script I currently use is using "ls -FCRlhLoprt" to list every file inside of a root directory recursively to a text document. The problem is, every time I run the script, ls includes that document in its output so the text document grows each time I run it. I believe I can use -i or --ignore, but how can I use that when ls is using a few variables? I keep getting errors:

```
ls "$lsopt" "$masroot"/ >> "$masroot"/"$client"_"$jobnum"_"$mas"_drive_contents.txt . #this works
```

If I try:

```
ls -FCRlhLoprt --ignore=""$masroot"/"$client"_"$jobnum"_"$mas"_drive_contents.txt"" "$masroot"/ >> "$masroot"/"$client"_"$jobnum"_"$mas"_drive_contents.txt #this does not work
```

I get errors. I basically want to not include the output back into the 2nd time I run this command.

Additional, all I am trying to do is create an easy to read document of every file inside of a directory recursively. If there is a better way, please let me know.

Comment: `--ignore` is GNU / Linux only. Are you running this command on something other than Linux?

Comment: Also, 'I get errors.' is not at all helpful. What errors?

Comment: 'If there is a better way, please let me know.' -- you might try using `find` which is designed for such applications.

Comment: write the result file in the *parent directory* of your starting directory. The redirection operator creates the file *before* the `ls` command starts.

Comment: I am on macOS - forgot to mention that.

Comment: @dawg - would -i work on mac?

Comment: @JamieMetzger: *'would -i work on mac?'* The flag is supported (ie, not an error) but does something totally different. `-i      For each file, print the file's file serial number (inode number).` You can read this yourself by typing `man ls` at a Bash prompt.

Comment: @glennjackman: *write the result file in the parent directory of your starting directory.* Hard to do when he is starting with `/` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> Additional, all I am trying to do is create an easy to read document of every file inside of a directory recursively. If there is a better way, please let me know.

To list every file in a directory recursively, the `find` command does exactly what you want, and admits further programmatic manipulation of the files found if you wish.

### Examples:

#### To list every file under the current directory, recursively:

```
find ./ -type f
```

#### To list files under `/etc/` and `/usr/share`, showing their owners and permissions:

```
find /etc /usr/share -type f -printf "%-100p %#m %10u %10g\n"
```

#### To show line counts of all files recursively, but ignoring subdirectories of `.git`:

```
find ./ -type f ! -regex ".*\.git.*" -exec wc -l {} +
```

#### To search under `$masroot` but ignore files generated by past searches, and dump the results into a file:

```
find "$masroot" -type f ! -regex ".*/[a-zA-Z]+_[0-9]+_.+_drive_contents.txt" | tee "$masroot/${client}_${jobnum}_${mas}_drive_contents.txt"
```

(Some of that might be slightly different on a Mac. For more information see `man find`.)